# How can to find tolerance in topology?

Tags: coordinate-system, polygon, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I am working with Topology plugins in Qgis 3.8, but I don't see tolerance in topology. I hope to get help. I have attach images.
[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't see tolerance in topology"?

Comment: @Erik I think tolerance refer to what is the smallest coordinate difference that is considered as effectively different (for exemple if you have data with different coordinate precision like 3.12658 and 3.13 setting tolerance to 0.01 round both coordinate to 3.13 and topology will consider the coordinate to be equal); not being able to specify it may effectively prevent you to use it on two dataset with different precision.

Comment: @JR How do I see tolerance in topology plugins with Qgis3?

Comment: @HuynhMiPham,  I can't find a setting for that, hopefully somebody else know the answer...